# Ui slider and bootstrap 3 carousel together

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, uislider

I want to use a ui slider to change the carousel images. I want to use [Nouislider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider) and the default Bootstrap carousel.

Currently I have the following codes:

```
$('.noUiSlider').noUiSlider({
    range: [0,6],
    start: 0,
    handles: 1,
    orientation: "vertical",
    slide: function () {
        var values = $(this).val();
        $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel(values[0]);             
    }
});
```

Consider the following lines from Bootstrap carousel documentation:

> .carousel(number)
>
> Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an
>   array).

It gives an error **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '0'**, I can not understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:

```
var value = parseInt( $(this).val() );
$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel(value);
```